# Default color change in ContentLoadingProgressBar

Tags: android, progress-bar, androidx

I am using **androidx** in my project and somewhere i am using **ContentLoadingProgressBar** but i am not able to change default color.

I have tried with **android:indeterminateTint** but can't help.

If anyone having any idea regarding this plz suggest

```
<androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extend the default theme and override colorAccent

```
<style name="AppTheme.WhiteAccent">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item> <!-- Whatever color you want-->
</style>
```

add ContentLoadingProgressBar  the android:theme attribute:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set both **style** and **android:theme** with accent color you want your progress bar in. Refer below code snippets:

> layout.xml

```
 <androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:theme="@style/ContentLoadingProgress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
```

> styles.xml

```
  <style name="ContentLoadingProgress">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorWhite</item>
  </style>
```